# How to prevent Android app from getting uninstalled during deployment with Xamarin Studio?

Tags: android, deployment, xamarin.android, uninstallation, xamarin-studio

Every time I deploy a new version of an Android app with Xamarin Studio the app gets uninstalled first and then installed again. This is causing some problems for me because I'm using XPrivacy on my devices.

I wonder if there is a way to simply deploy the new version without uninstalling them in the first place (like when deploying with Android Studio or Eclipse)?

Comment: Same problem here. Setting the preserve data/cache option doesn't wok.

Answer (score 3):

When building and deploying apps to your device, by default Xamarin will delete any existing application data/cache. This is not always ideal as it resets your data as if it were a fresh install.

To preserve data, you need to update the option:

- In Xamarin Studio, select Tools > Options > Projects > Android... Check "Preserve data/cache between application deploys"
- In Visual Studio, select Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings... Check "Preserve data/cache between application deploys"

Once you do this, any shared preferences or data files created in the local application folder will remain.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. But it doesn't work. The app get's uninstalled nonetheless. Btw. I'm running the latest Xamarin Studio 5.5 (Build 227) on a Mac. Now what?

Comment: Is your phone rooted? I've had issues where the app data would be deleted even with this option checked.

Comment: how comes xamarin guys keep this option off by default! i am sure plentry of programmers abandoned xamarin development because of this.thank you for this suggestion by the way.

Comment: I have the feeling this option just restores the data after an uninstall/install cycle. It does not prevent the original problem.

Comment: This option doesn't work for me on Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Same here VS 2017.