# Why re-installing an application sometimes clears SP although app backup is allowed?

Tags: android, xamarin, sharedpreferences, backup, manifest

I noticed that re-installing my application (building it again and again in debug mode) sometimes clears my SP and sometimes not.
I thought that adding android:allowBackup="true" in the application tab in the Manifest.xml file might restore it anytime I re-build the app.

```
<application 
android:allowBackup="true" 
.
.
.
>
```

1. Does building the app over and over actually uninstall it and then re-install it? And if it actually works like that, does it work the same for release mode?
2. What android:allowBackup="true" actually does? I thought it creates a permanent file on the phone pointing to the important data that needs to be backed-up.
3. When updating an app via Google Play, what is the actual process? Is the app uninstalled and then re-installed? Or does it just update the necessary code?How does it affect the memory?
4. What is the real reason of my Shared-Preferences actually getting deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to things like shared preferences, they typically should be preserved between debugging sessions (assuming you are not manually deleting the app from the emulator/device).

Check Visual Studio's setting to ensure that it is *trying* to preserve data/cache directories:

- [Preserve data/cache between application deploys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26371412/4984832)

Read the section on "Fast Deployment" for how Xamarin handles debug build updates:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-process

During development "Auto Backup" (`android:allowBackup="true"`) is pretty much irrelevant, see the conditions below in which is it back up to your Google Drive account.

> Backups occur automatically when all of the following conditions are met:
>
> - The user has enabled backup on the device.
> - At least 24 hours have elapsed since the last backup.
> - The device is idle.
> - The device is connected to a Wi-Fi network (if the device user hasn't opted in to mobile-data backups).

The Android ([Back up user data with Auto Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup)) documentation cover this in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For enabling backup, should I add a login system to Google Play account? Or does it happen automatically?

Comment: @DanielReyhanian Auto Backup : This happens at the OS level, not the app level. *Typically* the Android setup requires a google account (depending upon where in the world the phone is deployed of course) and thus the phone has access to a Google Drive. So if your app is coming for the Google Play Store, then nothing is to be done. If you app is deployed in China via a local Android Store, auto-backup (via Google Drive) would not happen, but that does not mean backup would not occur (the phone's OEM would have had to implement that OS feature for what local service(s) are available to the devic